# Realizar consulta em duas tabelas diferentes no mesmo select

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso realizar uma busca em duas tabelas diferentes e dar `echo` nos resultados separadamente! Acho que seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM tabela1 T1 UNION (SELECT* FROM tabela2 T2)";
$con = mysqli_query ($db,$consulta);
while ($Dado = mysqli_fetch_array($con)) {
  echo $DadosT1; // Aqui resultado da primeira tabela
  echo $DadosT2; // Aqui resultado da segunda tabela
}
```

Alguém pode me esclarecer se isso é possível e como faz?

Comment: Duas tabelas diferentes? quando se usa UNION não dá, as tabelas devem seguir a mesma quantidade de campos e tipos ! mas, quais os campos da tabela1 e os campos da tabela2?

Comment: São vários campos deferentes entre as duas tabelas. Aném, precisava fazer essa consulta dessa forma...

Answer (score 1):

Você não poderia realizar separadamente para atingir seu objetivo? Algo como:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM tabela1";
$con = mysqli_query ($db,$consulta);
while ($Dado = mysqli_fetch_array($con)) {
  echo $Dado; // Aqui resultado da primeira tabela
}

$consulta = "SELECT* FROM tabela2 T2";
$con = mysqli_query ($db,$consulta);
while ($Dado = mysqli_fetch_array($con)) {
  echo $Dado; // Aqui resultado da segunda tabela
}
```

Desculpe se não entendi corretamente seu objetivo.

Comment: Posso, más não consigo que dê certo pois estou utilizando a tabela1 para popular uma tabela no HTML, e preciso pegar uma informação da tabela2 para incluir em uma coluna da mesma tabela no HTML, e fazendo a busca separadamente, as informações da tabela2 aparecem repetidas pois estão dentro do `while` da tabela1.

Fora isso tudo, eu ainda preciso realizar a busca na tabela2 de acordo com uma informação da tabela1, por exemplo: pegar o nome das pessoas de acordo com a matricula fornecida pela tabela1. Desculpa, ficou meio enrolado, mas é isso que preciso fazer...

Comment: Neste caso, o que você precisa fazer é realizar um INNER JOIN entre as tabelas.
É bem simples de entender, dá um Google em INNER JOIN. ;)